# Filtrar Json vindo do banco utilizando Lambda C#

Tags: c#, json, expressões-lambda

Estou iniciando no desenvolvimento e estou precisando de uma ajuda.
Tenho esse Json que estou recebendo do banco.
Porém preciso filtrar as informações por name para o meu metodo retornar.
Por ex. Se o name = "Percent Processor Time", ele só deve retornar o array de valores atrelado a ele.

```
[
{
    "name": "Percent Processor Time",
    "jsonValues": [
        {
            "time": "2018-01-22T18:10:30Z",
            "instanceName": "RD00155D00C625",
            "value": 15.3125
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "Requests per Sec",
    "jsonValues": [
        {
            "time": "2018-01-22T18:10:30Z",
            "instanceName": "RD00155D00C625",
            "value": 8.5666666666666664
        }            
    ]
},
{
    "name": "Handles",
    "jsonValues": [
        {
            "time": "2018-01-22T18:11:00Z",
            "instanceName": "RD00155D00C625",
            "value": 2221.0
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "Threads",
    "jsonValues": [
        {
            "time": "2018-01-22T18:11:00Z",
            "instanceName": "RD00155D00C625",
            "value": 69.0
        }
    ]
},
```

Meu método está da seguinte forma.

```
public List<JsonValue> GetPerformance(DateTime StartDate, DateTime EndDate, string Name)
{
  var db = new Core.Database.EntitiesContext();
  var performance = new PerformanceInfo();
  performance.MarkTraceDates();
  List<JsonValue> retorno = null;//Criando lista para armazenar dados

  try
  {        
    var resultSearch = db.Performances.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedDate).First();//buscando no banco

    retorno = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JsonValue>>(resultSearch.Json);//deserializando Json na lista

  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    Console.Write(e.Message);
  }

  List<JsonValue> filtrado = new List<JsonValue>();
  filtrado = retorno.Select(x => new JsonValue
  {
    Name = x.Name,
    JsonValues = x.Properties.Data.Values.Select(y => new JsonValues { InstanceName = y.InstanceName, Time = y.Time, Value = y.Value }).ToList()
  }).ToList();
```

Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode alterar o trecho

```
 filtrado = retorno.Select(x => new JsonValue
  {
    Name = x.Name,
    JsonValues = x.Properties.Data.Values.Select(y => new JsonValues { InstanceName = y.InstanceName, Time = y.Time, Value = y.Value }).ToList()
  }).ToList();
```

Por

```
 filtrado = retorno.Select(x => new JsonValue
      {
        Name = x.Name,
        JsonValues = x.Properties.Data.Values.Select(y => new JsonValues { InstanceName = y.InstanceName, Time = y.Time, Value = y.Value }).ToList()
      }).Where(a=> a.Name.Equals(Name)).ToList();
```

Comment: Valeu amigo, meu ajudou muito!!!